# Forward video stream from local server to html page

Tags: apache, webserver, streaming

I have Apache server running, and it has a website running on it. I also have an IP webcam, and it is not secure to make this webcam available to the internet, but I want it's feed to be accessible. Is there a way to forward 192.168.10.100:8080/video stream, so that it would be accessible via Apache from website.com/video without exposing 192.168.10.100:8080 to the internet? ACL to limit access to 192.168.10.100:8080 is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Forward port 8080 through your router, or ask your ISP to make forwarding to the port that you want, to be open from the outside.

See here: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

This is your IP, which is seen from the outside.

Use the "outside" IP instead of your local, or set DNS,